# Horizontal whitespace on mobile WooCommerce My Account page with "Account Details" tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the WooCommerce "My Account" shortcode ([woocommerce_my_account]) on a standard Wordpress page, nothing else is on the page. When the "Account Details" tab is clicked on mobile the page then becomes scrollable horizontally which I don't want. You can see the whitespace to the right of the header. Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.
[image: Mobile Page]